# Problem with displaying Persian text with tkinter in CentOS7

Tags: python, tkinter, centos7, farsi

I've wrote a very simple python code to display a window with window title being "سلام" and a label inside that window also saying "سلام"!

Here's the code I wrote:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("سلام")
tk.Label(root, text="سلام", font=('Arial', 16)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is when I run the code using Windows 10, everything works finem but when I run it on CentOS7, the title displays fine but the label displays encoded.

I am using Python 3.8.18 with TkVersion 8.6

**Update**
Here's a list of fonts available on my CentOS7 system(checked with `fc-list | grep -i "arial"`):

```
/usr/share/fonts/Ariali.TTF: Arial:style=kurzíva,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/Arial.TTF: Arial:style=Κανονικά,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/AriBlk.TTF: Arial Black:style=Regular,Standard
/usr/share/fonts/Arialbi.TTF: Arial:style=tučné kurzíva,Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/Arialbd.TTF: Arial:style=tučné,Bold
```

**Problem solved** : switched to PyQt

[image: programm in centos7]

Comment: Do you have Arial installed on CentOS7? If not, tk will probably fall back on another font. I don't know how exactly that font is chosen. But if that font doesn't have the characters, you're out of luck and need to find another way. One option is to ship your own font.

Comment: works fine for me on windoze

Comment: I'll check and update the post. @Joooeey

Comment: @PaulRandleman On windows it works fine for me too. It doesn't work on CentOS7

Comment: @SepehrGolestanian did you try using `AriBlk` instead of `Arial`?

I'm assuming your localization settings are the reason that `Arial` has the `style=Κανονικά,Regular`?

Comment: @PaulRandleman No, solved the problem by switching to PyQt